# Grund für Suspendierung eines Users?

Tags: discussion

Warum wurde der User [Prishon](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/50555/prishon) bis August 2031 (also für die nächsten 10 Jahre) suspendiert? Ich kann weder hier auf German.stackexchange noch auf anderen Seiten des Stackexchange-Universums irgendwelche Aktivitäten dieses Users erkennen, die auch nur annähernd eine solche Maßnahme rechtfertigen würden. Auch auf anderen Stackexchange-Seiten hat er sinnvolle Fragen gestellt und auch an seinen Antworten und Kommentaren ist nichts auszusetzen.

Und warum wollen hier auf German.stackexchange 4 User [eine Frage dieses Users](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/65868/1487) (bisher seine einzige auf German.stackexchange) schließen, die (Stand 13.8.2021) 13 Upvotes und 3 Antworten mit insgesamt 60 Upvotes generiert hat?

Ich verstehe auch nicht ganz, warum 16 User den Kommentar von RedSonja unter dieser Frage upgevotet haben. Die Frage lässt sich nämlich nicht keineswegs durch Konsultation von Wörterbüchern beantworten.

Comment: Das sind erstmal zwei getrennte Fragen. Die Antwort auf die erste Frage ist, dass die [Gründe für Suspendierungen grundsätzlich nicht öffentlich gemacht werden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293213/255554). Ich denke nicht, dass wir hier viel darüber reden können. Die Antwort auf die zweite Frage ist vermutlich, dass die Frage bis vor kurzem äußerst schlecht betitelt war, und wenn man nur den Titel liest, diese Reaktionen durchaus angemessen sind.

Comment: Ok, den Teil 1 muss ich wohl so akzeptieren. Aber wenn du mit Teil 2 recht haben solltest, erschüttert mich das schon. Wie kann man eine Frage zum Schließen vorschlagen, ohne sie überhaupt gelesen zu haben? Allerdings würde das erklären, warum es so viele Schließungen gibt, die einfach nicht nachvollziehbar sind. Ich habe ohnehin schon seit längerem den Eindruck, dass manche User blindlings auch die unsinnigsten Close-Vorschläge akzeptieren, die in den Review-Queues liegen, nur um irgendwann den Steward-Badge zu bekommen. Ich weiß nicht, ob das wirklich zielführend ist.

Comment: Schlechte Reviews sind ein immer wiederkehrendes Problem auf SE. Wenn Du dies diskutieren möchtest, werde ich Dich sicher nicht davon abhalten, aber ich würde es bevorzugen, wenn dies losgelöst von dieser spezifischen Frage wäre. — *Wie kann man eine Frage zum Schließen vorschlagen, ohne sie überhaupt gelesen zu haben?* – In aller Fairness ist das Problem zweiseitig: Wie kann man einer Frage einen Titel geben, der weit am Ziel vorbeischießt? Ein schließwürdiger Titel ist schon ein Problem, da irgendwer immer diesen beantwortet. Kann man natürlich auch mit einem Edit lösen.